# How do I disable mini-http on boot?

Tags: boot, services

I'd like to disable `mini-http` on boot.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mini-httpd disable
```

The above command does not exist. Only `start`|`stop`|`restart`|`force-reload`options are available and these only stop the service till the next reboot.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `sudo update-rc.d mini-httpd disable` OR `sudo update-rc.d remove` and restore to defaults with

`sudo update-rc.d mini-httpd defaults`

You can use `-f` flag to force the changes.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/default/mini-httpd` has an option `START=1`. Set it to 0 and it will not automatically start.

From command line

```
nano /etc/default/mini-httpd
```

Change the 1 to a 0. Hit control-x and save.